# Time based field update (3 hours prior to date/time field value)

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

Date/Time field is a custom field in Leads (AppointmentFixedAt).

The idea is that another custom field SMSToggle (checkbox) should be set to true three hours prior to the time set in the AppointmentFixedAt field.

The requirement is to send an SMS reminder three hours prior to the set time. If the SMSToggle is checked, a trigger calls a future method to send the SMS.

I am convinced this can be done with Time based workflow, but can't put together how?

Please Not: I am Only looking for time based field update.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to send an SMS after having the SMSToggle populated, you can use process builder. Find below an example with Account. Once Account is updated or created, the Criteria is check if the field is true. Then the action will be to call an ApexClass with Invocable methods. This [blog post](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com.es/2015/02/lightning-process-builder-and-invocable.html) from [Keir Bowden](https://twitter.com/bob_buzzard) is a good example for that.

[image]

If you need to Update the checkbox and then send the message if the time is 3 hours ahead a field value, you can also use Process builder.

1. When Account is created, no Criteria, schedule the action and update the checkbox. Find screenshot below

[image]

Comment: I only want to set the SMSToggle to true 3 hours before the time set in the field (AppointmentFixedAt). I am already able to send SMS on non time based criteria.

Comment: I have updated my answer with another screenshot. Hope this helps you.